# The program is not printing it's a tie. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

The following program is not printing "It's a tie" when the computer's choice is the same as the player's choice.

```
import random

print("welcome to rock,paper, scissors and dynamite game!")

moves=["rock","paper","scissors","dynamite"]

for i in range(1,6):

    print("Round",i)

    user_play=input("player "+str(i)+" choice?").lower().strip(" ")

    play_moves=random.choice(moves)

    computer_play=input("computer choices:"+play_moves).lower().strip(" ")
    
    if user_play== computer_play:
        print("It's a tie!")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program that you just wrote doesn't actually print the computer's random choice but instead it again prompts for user input one more time.

```
computer_play=input("computer choices:"+play_moves).lower().strip(" ")
```

Instead you might wanted to write it like this -

```
print("Computer Choices : " + play_moves)
```

And moreover, at the end of the program, it doesn't check equality of the random computer guess (`play_moves`) and the user input (`user_play`) but instead it checks the equality of the second user input (`computer_play`) with the first input.

```
if user_play== computer_play:
```

So, to compare the user input and the computer's random guess you would do this -

```
if user_play == play_moves:
```

Ask in the comments if you still have any doubts and I will improve my answer.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The computer's choice is stored in the `play_moves` variable so you should compare `user_play` with `play_moves` to check if it's a tie:

```
if user_play == play_moves:
    print("It's a tie!")
```